# Start Time and End Time in JMeter Scheduler

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, stress-testing

I am working on JMeter version 2.5.1 and I want to set up a Scheduler for my Thread Group.

I set the following values for scheduler fields:

```
Start Time = 2011/12/13 11:30:00
End Time = 2011/12/13 11:32:00
Duration (seconds) = 3
Startup delay (seconds) = 5
```

My threads start after the delay of 5 seconds and keep running up to 3 seconds duration. But I cannot see any effect of Start Time and End Time on my threads.

Kindly tell me what do these fields do in the process of running of threads.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Jmeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group),

> Delay overrides Start Time, and Duration overrides End Time.

If you remove your delay and duration, the test should run for the scheduled time!

Comment: Please try to answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487560/jmeter-http-authorization-manager-error) question as well.

Comment: FWIW, I found that I had to enter '0' in the Duration and Startup Delay fields to get JMeter to take notice of Start Time and End Time - leaving Duration and Startup Delay blank meant my tests didn't run.