# JMeter- HTTP Authorization Manager Error

Tags: http, testing, authorization, jmeter, stress-testing

I added an HTTP Authorization Manager to JMeter, an HTTP Request Default and an HTTP Proxy Server.
I configured my HTTP Authorization Manager control Panel as:

```
Base URL: http://www.gmail.com
Username: abc
Password: xxxxxxx
```

But I am getting error in internet explorer when I open http://gmail.com

> Error:
>
> There is a problem with this website's security certificate.
>
> The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority. The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or
> intercept any data you send to the server.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to log in to gmail to read emails via Jmeter?

If so, it's not as easy as pointing to the gmail URL and using BASIC authentication. You could get an idea of what's involved by using [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) to record the actions you want to do and then export it to Jmeter.

That said, this is not a good approach.

I'd be looking at using the POP3 interface - trying to simulate a browser with Jmeter for a site like gmail which changes every day could be very difficult. It should be possible to write a Java POP3 client (or better yet, find an open source one) and call it from your Jmeter script.

Comment: actually I just want to check what HTTP Authorization Manager do?
I have tried many ways but I am unable to understand its purpose

Comment: Haha ok, it's used for websites that use [BASIC authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). That's where you get the browser dialog box that asks for username/password. I'd really recommend reading the [Jmeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html)

Comment: This in particular! http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager

Comment: I've gone through this but what do I understand is when user sets username and password in HTTP Authorization Manager and enters some inner URL for a website for example abc.com/index.php then this should be opened without asking username or password. Because I have provided username and password in HTTP Authorization Manager. Am I right?

Comment: Most routers these days use BASIC authentication for their admin consoles. If you have such a router and you know the username/password, you could use the IP address as the URL, and the username/password, and you should be able to successfully log into your router's admin console.

Comment: If you have your own web server then you could test with that (ideal if you know what you're doing) too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Last question: Could you please refer me to some example of this on any website? In which there's a demo to use HTTP Authorization Manager

Comment: I had trouble finding any. This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509278/authentication-test-servers) doesn't help much either. I found [this](http://test.webdav.org/) (see the auth-basic section), but only the authentication bit works, the actual page can't be found once you login (you get a 404). So you could use it, but just be aware you should be expecting a 404 coming back.